# NSDateFormatter @"mmddyyy"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Helo,
I'm trying the bunch of code and it is giving null. Is there any problem in this code?

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // get NSDate from old string format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mmddyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"02012002"];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    // get string in new date format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strMyDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@\n\n********************************************************",strMyDate);
```

the output is

```
2011-06-09 12:49:17.957 TestPrj[3054:207] (null)
2011-06-09 12:49:17.959 TestPrj[3054:207] (null)

********************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You r missing one 'y' there in second line-
it either should be -

> dateFormatter
>   setDateFormat:@"mmddyyyy"];
>
> or dateFormatter
>   setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyy"];
```

**EDIT**

In my previous version `DD` did work in this example though it will produce wrong results beginning with february -> back to `dd`.

Use `MM` for the months else it'll parse it as minutes.

Please refer to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35 / Locale Data Markup Language (LDML)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thanks... for the quick response... Could you tell me why it is so?

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore explained in post.